# Is there any documentation available on the internals of netrw?

Tags: netrw, plugin-system

I have found [fairly clear documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-externapp) on the usage and customization of `netrw`, but a perusal of the plugin source code shows only method-level comments, and does not give a good indication of the places one needs to modify to add a new protocol.

Does there exist documentation for people attempting to implement new remote protocols?

Comment: `:help netrw` is the only documentation on netrw but you can get in touch with the author on the vim_use/vim_dev mailing lists.